# Solutions of linear ODE with INTEGER coefficeints

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, integers, frobenius-method

A meromorphic linear ODE can be solved by Frobenius method at a regular singular point. I'm interested in the solutions with integer coefficients, i.e.
$$
f(x)=x^\alpha\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nx^n,\ \ \alpha\in\mathbb{C},\ a_n\in\mathbb{Z}.
$$
I would like know what kind of linear ODE has such solutions and what kind of linear ODE does not. Does anyone know criteria?

Comment: Whenever the recurrence relation for coefficients you get when using the Frobenius method admits for the integer solutions you have the solution with integer coefficients?

Comment: That's right. But the recurrence relation is not always easy. So I want other criteria, if there are any.